# Send html and plain text email simultaneously with PHP Mailer

Tags: php

I would like to send both html and plain text simultaneously in an email. I found [this pretty straightforward tutorial](http://kevinjmcmahon.net/articles/22/html-and-plain-text-multipart-email-/) but it used the mail() function to send the email.
How do I transform this code send an email with the PHP Mailer class?

```
//specify the email address you are sending to, and the email subject
$email = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'Email Subject';

//create a boundary for the email. This 
$boundary = uniqid('np');

//headers - specify your from email address and name here
//and specify the boundary for the email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Your Name \r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

//here is the content body
$message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Plain text body
$message .= "Hello,\nThis is a text email, the text/plain version.
\n\nRegards,\nYour Name";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Html body
$message .= "
 Hello,
This is a text email, the html version.

Regards,
Your Name";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

//invoke the PHP mail function
mail('', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See below:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->WordWrap = 80;
$mail->Host = "smtp.thehost.com"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;

$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from; // First name, last name
$mail->AddAddress($to, "First name last name");
#$mail->AddReplyTo("reply@thehost.com", "Reply to address");

$mail->Subject =  $subject;
$mail->Body =  $htmlMessage; 
$mail->AltBody  =  $textMessage;    # This automatically sets the email to multipart/alternative. This body can be read by mail clients that do not have HTML email capability such as mutt.

if(!$mail->Send())
{
  throw new Exception("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

Thanks to http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/129-how-to-send-both-html-and-text-emails-with-php-and-phpmailer and Google. SMTP use might be optional for you.

Comment: Wonderful! I googled this but couldn't find anything about PHP Mailers AltBody attribute. Works like a charm, my email has just received 9.9 instead of 8.3 on http://www.mail-tester.com!

Comment: Anything what I need to take care of, that the plain-text body looks like it should? My newlines are always removed... `$message['plaintext'] = $PHPMailer->html2text($message['html']);`

Comment: Try `$PHPMailer->html2text(nl2br($message['html']))`

Comment: Works great! I scored 9/10 now instead of 7.9 . :) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There is a function for that in PHPMailer: `msgHTML()`

```php
# Minimum code to send an email:
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();

$phpmailer->From = $from;
$phpmailer->FromName = $from_name;

$phpmailer->AddAddress( $to, $to_name );

$phpmailer->Subject = $subject;

$phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$phpmailer->msgHTML( $htmlMessage ); # <- right here!

# Use PHP's mail() instead of SMTP:
$phpmailer->IsMail();

$phpmailer->Send();
```

> Create a message from an HTML string.
>     Automatically makes modifications for inline images and backgrounds
>     and creates a plain-text version by converting the HTML.
>     Overwrites any existing values in $this->Body and $this->AltBody

See full function's code on Github:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L3299

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

**Debug levels**

Setting the `PHPMailer->SMTPDebug` property to these numbers or constants (defined in the `SMTP` class) results in different amounts of output:

- `SMTP::DEBUG_OFF` (`0`): Disable debugging (you can also leave this
  out completely, 0 is the default).
- `SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT` (`1`): Output messages sent by the client.
- `SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER` (`2`): as 1, plus responses received from the
  server (this is the most useful setting).
- `SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION` (`3`): as 2, plus more information about the
  initial connection - this level can help diagnose STARTTLS failures.
- `SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL` (`4`): as 3, plus even lower-level
  information, very verbose, don't use for debugging SMTP, only
  low-level problems.

You don't need to use levels above 2 unless you're having trouble connecting at all - it will just make output more verbose and more difficult to read.

Note that you will get no output until you call send(), because no SMTP conversation takes place until you do that.

**Link**: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging