# Send an e-mail with html and text

Tags: phpmailer, joomla3.5

I'm using Joomla's integrated version of PHPmailer to send an e-mail.
I have already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507534/5186325), but something is not working for me. An exception gets thrown at the AltBody line and the PHP fails to reach the Send line.

By commenting out the AltBody line, the HTML version of my mail is sent and it works fine.

I also used setBody instead of Body, because Body just doesn't work (from further reading done today I suspect that's because I used `$mail->Body($msg)` instead of `$mail->Body = $msg`, and "Body is an attribute, not a method", said Marc B in a comment.)

Is this related to me not using SMTP?
Can this be because of the content I'm trying to assign to AltBody? (It is a variable built by concatenating several strings of text that use \n for newlines.)
Is this because of something else?

<sub>Unfortunately, I can't post the code of the whole php. I will try to remember it and I will check it tomorrow and progressively correct it.</sub>

```
$msg = '<p>some html';
$msg .= 'some more html. Escaped "apostrophes" like \' used because of language </p>';
$txt = "some text,\nusing doublequotes as the delimiter.";

$mail = JFactory::getMailer();
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
$mail->setSender('example@example.com');
$mail->addRecipient('you@example.com');
$mail->setFrom('example@example.com');
$mail->setSubject('test mail');
$mail->setBody($msg);
$mail->AltBody($txt); # not working, commenting the line out works.
$mail->ClearCCs();
$mail->ClearBCCs();
$mail->AddBCC('example@example.com');
$mail->ClearAttachments(); # I know, this is not a cycle. But I'm not sure about injection, better delete it in case someone managed to add it.
$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();
if (empty($honeypot)) {
    $mail->send();
    exit('Mail sent');
}
```

This is all inside a `try`, with the `catch` for catching exceptions and echoing them.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to debug your code if you don't post anything? Read the PHPMailer docs to see how to set AltBody

Comment: @Synchro I managed to copy some more. I hope it is enough.

Comment: Just read the PHPMailer docs and the code. There is no setBody method; Body and AltBody are properties, so just set them. You do not need to call clearAttachments.

Comment: There is no setSender or setSubject either, unless your wrapper adds them.

Comment: @Synchro setBody, setSender and setSubject all work, so I guess Jfactory added them. I will look into its documentation and see what they do and how they interfere with setting AltBody (which I also tried as a property, to no avail).

Answer (score 1):

Please try with code, it may helps you:

```
$mail = JFactory::getMailer();
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
$mail->addRecipient($email_to);
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->setSender(array($mailfrom, $fromname));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($body);
$sent = $mail->Send();
```

Comment: This is sent from a no-reply address. No need to use addReplyTo in my case. Also no need to add a fromname, for the same reason.
How does this solve my problem?

Comment: Please try out same code using blank from name and comment replayto line may be that will work fine as per your requirement.