# Howto send HTML and TXT email via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

I want and at the same time in an e-mail a txt and a html Version of the body.
so that users who have activated only txt can still read the text.

#### Thats a example with text-mail-body from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object) :

```
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com",
                  "replies@example.com",
                  "TPS report status",
                  "What is the status of those TPS reports?");
```

#### and a example with htmlBody from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54670/send-html-email-from-a-spreadsheet-using-a-different-alias :

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'your@emailaddress.com',         // recipient
    'test GmailApp',                 // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: html                 // advanced options
    }
  );
```

Comment: For comparison here is a solution in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507176/send-html-and-plain-text-email-simultaneously-with-php-mailer

Comment: my best result: `function  onSubmit(){
  var htmlBody = "Hello<br>This is a <b>test</b>.<br>Bye.";
  var body = htmlBody.replace(/<.+?>/g, ""); 
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: 'to@gmail.com', subject: 'from onSubmit 18-12-06_23-29+', body: {htmlBody: htmlBody, from: "Myself <from@gmail.com>"}});
}`

Comment: this maybe works: `function sendMultipartEmail(to,from,subject,htmlBody){
  // var htmlBody = "Hello<br>This is a <b>test</b>.<br>Bye.";
  var body = htmlBody.replace(/<.+?>/g, ""); 
  var advancedOptions = {
   to: to, 
   subject: subject,
   body: body,
   htmlBody: htmlBody,
   from: from
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(advancedOptions);
}`